# Question appearing blurred (less visible). Any explanation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Please, find a screenshot of my PhysSE homepage. Is there any explanation why that question would appear semi-visible? [image]

Comment: Do you have any "ignored tags" in the list on the RHS of the page?

Comment: Yes. Alles klar. It was set by mistake for one of the tags.

Comment: Canonical: *[What do “watched tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-watched-tags-and-ignored-tags-do/19177#19177)*